# Manifold structure on a set of matrices

Tags: matrices, manifolds, differential-topology

Let $Ω$ denote the $((n+1)×(n+1))$ matrix given by
\begin{bmatrix}
-1&0\\0&I_n
\end{bmatrix}
where $I_n$ is the $n×n$ identity matrix.

Let $X=\{A∈M_{n+1}(\mathbb{R}):A^tΩA=Ω\}$. How can I show that $X$ is a manifold? What will its dimension be? I am thinking of using the determinant map. It is easy to see that the determinant of each element of $X$ is $1$ or $-1$. What next? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Maybe write $A$ by blocks? The last $n\times n$ block is the set of orthogonal matrices, to begin with...

Comment: https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Lorentz+group

Comment: Regular value theorem?

Answer (score 1):

$X$ is a group, so a neighbourhood of the identity matrix $I$ is mapped to a neighbourhood of any $A \in X$ by the map
$B \mapsto AB$.  So it suffices to prove that a neighbourhood of $I$ is a manifold.  This can be done using the implicit function theorem.